# How to rename a device in my Microsoft account?

Tags: microsoft-account

I recently built a desktop PC with Windows 10 and signed in with my Microsoft account. However, since Windows 10 never asked me for the computer name during setup, it got associated with my MS account using a pre-generated name (eg. DESKTOP-HSJGKRI).

I have since renamed the PC, but the [MS account devices page](https://account.microsoft.com/devices) doesn't seem to have picked up the new name. I tried removing that PC from my account, then signing in again, but it still got associated with the old name.

How can I rename the device manually? Alternatively, how can I force the MS account page to show the new name?